# Does the this function contain a local variable?

Tags: variables, assembly, stack

The book I'm reading says that this function has a local variable. It also says that having a local variable for this function is important because it's recursive. Maybe I'm just blind or I don't understand how local variables work in assembly, but I don't see it.

```
.type factorial, @function
factorial:
    push %rbp               # Save old base pointer.
    mov  %rsp, %rbp         # Copy stack pointer to base pointer.
    mov  16(%rbp), %rax     # Save the argument in %rax.
    cmp  $1, %rax           # End of the factorial.
    je   end_factorial
    dec  %rax               # Decrement %rax.
    push %rax               # Push onto stack for next call to factorial.
    call factorial
    mov  16(%rbp), %rbx     # %rax has return value, so load arg into %rbx.
    imul %rbx, %rax         # Multiply that by result of last call to factorial.

end_factorial:
    # Restore stack pointer and base pointer to where they were
    # before function call.
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

Can registers be considered local variables? I though local variables were implemented with something like `sub $8, %rsp`.

Comment: Moving local variables into registers is one of the most important optimizations performed by the code optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are not defined through their implementation, but by their semantics.

### A definition

A variable is **local**, if every invocation of the function gets its own independent value for that variable, that's why you could say that the value of the variable is "local to the function".

Since this behavior can be achieved by using registers, that's a perfectly valid implementation.

### Saving and restoring local variables

However, since certain registers are considered caller-saved, the values may have to be put on the stack before calling nested functions, otherwise the values would be lost. Upon returning to the original function from the nested call, the value can then be restored into the register from the stack.

As has already been mentioned, a accessing a register is much faster than accessing the stack. Thus, they are preferred to main memory whenever possible.

However, I do not know why it couldn't just do `imul 16(%rbp), %rax` without the additional move operation. After all, the `imul` instruction allows the source operand to be in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

A register is a perfectly valid place to put a local variable. In fact, it is preferred to memory because access is much faster. I modified my LLVM demo page to compile this factorial algorithm at http://ellcc.org/demo/. For the x86-64 it comes up with

```
    .file   "/tmp/webcompile/_23578_0.c"
.text
.globl  fact
.align  16, 0x90
.type   fact,@function
fact:                                   # @fact
.cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
movl    $1, %eax
cmpq    $2, %rdi
jl  .LBB0_2
.align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:                                # %if.end
                                     # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
imulq   %rdi, %rax
decq    %rdi
cmpq    $1, %rdi
jg  .LBB0_1
.LBB0_2:                                # %return
ret
.Ltmp0:
.size   fact, .Ltmp0-fact
.cfi_endproc
```

Notice that in this case the compiler gets rid of recursion and uses only registers to do the calculation.